# How to use SFTP CSV SOURCE connector in kafka using key based authentication?

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect, confluent-platform, confluent-schema-registry

I am trying to use confluent Kafka SFTP CSV SOURCE Connector.  In this I need to authenticate that SFTP SERVER by using private key.

I don't know how to work with `tls.private.key`!

How can I achieve this?

> Sample Configuration:

```
{
    "tasks.max": "1",
    "connector.class": "io.confluent.connect.sftp.SftpCsvSourceConnector",
    "cleanup.policy": "NONE",
    "behavior.on.error": "IGNORE",
    "input.path": "/csv",
    "error.path": "/error",
    "finished.path": "/finish",
    "input.file.pattern": "sample.csv",
    "sftp.username": "rocky",
    "sftp.host": "192.168.52.69",
    "sftp.port": "22",
    "kafka.topic": "sample-with-cast",
    "csv.first.row.as.header": "true",
    "schema.generation.enabled": "true",
    "transforms": "Cast",
    "transforms.Cast.type": "org.apache.kafka.connect.transforms.Cast$Value",
    "transforms.Cast.spec": "ID:int32,ICCTHR_CaseCrThreshold:float64"
}
```

Note: I am sending request from postman!

Comment: Did you find a solution? I am in the same situation

Answer (score 0):

I am sure this is no longer of interest, but in order to use a private key, you need to set the parameter `tls.private.key`, `tls.public.key`, and `tls.passphrase`.

The format for the private key needs to be a single line string, with \r\n replacing line endings. The correct formatting is documented for the sink connector at https://docs.confluent.io/kafka-connect-sftp/current/sink-connector/configuration_options.html#security